# Growing a zpool raidz2 with larger disks?

Tags: zfs

I have Linux PC with RaidZ2 over 6 disks, 3T each. Disks is shared between several partitions; the zpool lays only on part 6 on each disk; other partitions are used for other purposes.

I am going to buy 6x4T.

My plan is to:

- boot a live CD that is not aware of ZFS
- copy each 3T disk onto a 4T disk
- create on each 4T disk a new partition n° 18
- reboot my normal system
- expand my zpool over all partitions 18

Will it work ? what's the command to expand the pool with a set of 6 partitions sda18...sdf18 ?

If its not possible, I have a fallback method I don't like: make partitions 18 as large as possible (probably 1T), dump sd[abcdef]6 into sd[abcdef]18, erase sd[abcdef]6, and then, ask the zpool to expand in a partition larger than it used to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cloning the 3T drives to 4T drives, don't add new partitions, just resize the existing ZFS partitions.

There's nothing stopping you from adding partitions as you plan but if you do so, performance will be abysmal because zfs would waste an enormous amount of time moving the disk heads back and forth from the middle of the drive (the existing `sd[a-f]6` partitions) to the end of the drive (the new `sd[a-f]18` partitions).  You'd have a pool that was effectively a raid-0 of two raidz6 vdevs, instead of just one raidz6 vdev.

If there are other partitions on the disks after your ZFS partitions, then move them to the end of the drive to make space for the ZFS partitions to grow, then expand the zfs partitions.   Rebooting to a Live CD or USB etc with `gparted` (e.g. a rescue CD/USB like [gparted](https://gparted.org/)) would be good for this.

Alternatively, move the ZFS partitions to just after the other partitions, and then move the other partitions to where ZFS used to be, and then move the ZFS partitions again and then, finally, resize the ZFS partitions.  This is a lot more work, will take a **lot** more time (all downtime!), and will probably rename/renumber all the moved partitions, so you'll need to update your configs where relevant.  The only real benefit would be that it would be easier to expand the zfs partitions again in future, if you get bigger drives.

After rebooting, you can use `zpool offline pool partition` followed by `zpool online -e pool partition` for each partition to expand the pool to use all available space.

**IMPORTANT:** perform **both** commands on ONE partition at a time.  Do **not** offline more than one partition simultaneously.  e.g.

```
for p in sd[abcdef]6; do
  zpool offline pool "$p"
  zpool online -e pool "$p"
done
```

From `man zpool-online`:

> `-e`      Expand the device to use all available space.  If the device is part of a mirror or raidz then all devices must be expanded before the new space will become available to the pool.

Actually, that quoted text isn't complete.  It should say something like "If the device is part of a mirror or raidz **vdev** then all devices **in that vdev** must be expanded before the new space will become available to the pool."

i.e. if you have a pool with multiple vdevs (e.g. multiple mirror vdevs and/or multiple raidz vdevs) then the vdevs can/will be expanded individually.

Comment: But PLEASE, don't use `/dev/sd?` device names. Create GPT partition labels and use those. Since the OP is replacing every device on the VDEV, now is the perfect time to rectify past oversights.

Comment: personally, I use `/dev/disk/by-id/` device names because I like to see the device brands, models, and serial numbers in `zpool status` (makes it easy for me to identify which drive needs to be pulled in case of failure).   But the OP is already using /dev/sd*, and this Q&A isn't about the pros and cons of zpool device naming choices.

Comment: Yes, labeling partitions based on drive SN is the current best practice, to my knowledge. A human-readable identifier is paramount.

Comment: Understood about the pros and cons but also important is identifying opportunities for redemption of past transgressions. ;)

Comment: How much time and reads will offline+online-e take ? is it going to be a quick command in seconds, or, will resilvering take hours after each online-e ? I agree that /dev/disk/by-id/ is technically better, but as said, this topic was about raidz expansion, not namespaces, so sd[abcdef]* was faster to type and lighter to read. My disks technically have 20 partitions each; I have designed my mdadm block and splitted it in reverse ordered partitions, with last part of mdadm just after ZFS, so that a simple shrink of mdadm would allow to expand zfs keeping zfs in one block. Thanks CAS.

Comment: resilvering should be quick, not much is going to be written to the other drives in the few seconds or less that a drive will be offline.  It won't need to resync the entire drive/partition after a quick offline and online, just whatever gets changed while that drive is offline.

Comment: BTW, my recommendation for anyone using ZFS is to set up a VM with a few virtual disks and experiment with the zpool and zfs commands on the VM.  Create snapshots and zfs send backups, both full and incremental. Destroy the pool and restore it from backup. Write trash over one of the VM's virtual disks from the host system to simulate corruption, remove one of the virtual disks and replace it with another one to simulate drive failure. Get some practice before you need to do this on your real system. And fire up the VM again for more practice before doing something new or difficult.

Comment: CAS you made a small mistake; <<zpool offline "$p";zpool online -e "$p">> => <<zpool offline TANK "$p";zpool online -e TANK "$p">> . Also, in bash, sd[abcdef]6 did not expand properly; I had to ... do it an othe way. It would have expanded nicely if I had run this from /dev folder; but run from ~/ I had to expand manually "sda6 sdb6 sdc6 ..." (not saying this against CAS, but if beginners come to read this page). The whole process took 30s, and I now have gained free space . Still need to buy new disks soon :) Today, I had just shrank MDADM/LVM in emergency. Thanks.

Comment: tip: to work on partition table, I use sgdisk; few tutos mention it, it's very easy to script. it can create 120 partitions in 10 seconds. Downside: it may not align partition begining on logical 2K/4K blocks; human has to handle this issue himself.

Comment: @Benoit-PierreDEMAINE fixed example loop, added example pool name.  it is meant to be an illustrative example, not code you run without examining, **understanding**, and adapting to suit your needs.   if you're using /dev/sd* names, run it in /dev.  otherwise extract the list of devices names with something based on `zpool list -v poolname | awk '/^    / { print $1}'` (note: there are **4** spaces in that regex because that's how much the current version of zpool indents device names).  if  you have multiple pools or multiple vdevs in a pool, you'll need to modify that to suit your system.

Comment: RE: `sgdisk`. yeah, i use that. Very useful when you need to clone the partition table from one drive to another (like you need to do when setting up zfs pools or raid arrays).   I use `gdisk` or `parted` to create the first partition table, then copy it with `sgdisk`.   For MBR (i.e. before GPT) I used `fdisk` to create the first, and then `sfdisk` to clone.

Comment: and, just to be completely clear, that `zpool list ... | awk` command above is also for illustrative purposes only.   it's an example of one method that might be useful in some circumstances, not a magic command for anyone to run as-is and expect to work perfectly for their specific needs.   e.g. if you have log, cache, or special devices in a vdev, you'll probably want to exclude them from the list of devices to be offlined and onlined.